# How to do something after responding the HTTP request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to know if its possible on Laravel 5 to do something after answering the HTTP Response.

For example, I want to answer to a server that made a request to me and after that start sending some emails and notification.

So that the server doesn't have to wait for me to send emails and notifications to have the answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's definitely posible! Checkout the documentation on Queues: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues.

Basically you can create a Job that implements the `ShouldQueue` interface and it will use the `QUEUE_DRIVER` that you specified in your .env file with a fallback to "sync" meaning it will happen synchronously.

Comment: This is not the correct answer since the "sync" driver starts a job as soon as it gets queued (therefore it's "synchronous"). The question was how tasks can be executed after the HTTP response has been sent.

Answer (score 1):

For laravel 6+ there is dispatchAfterResponse

```
dispatch($job)->afterResponse();
```

From the doc:

> You may also dispatch a closure and chain the afterResponse method
> onto the dispatch helper to execute a closure after the HTTP response
> has been sent to the browser:

```php
use App\Mail\WelcomeMessage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
 
dispatch(function () {
    Mail::to('taylor@example.com')->send(new WelcomeMessage);
})->afterResponse();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#dispatching-after-the-response-is-sent-to-browser